# facebook messgaes getting sender name

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

i am using facebook fql to get users mailboxes.

following query returns all the values.

```
SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, attachment, 
viewer_id FROM message WHERE thread_id = <thread_id>
```

I want to get the auther_name and viewer_name.

right now i am using this trick to get names from ID's but its very slow, because first i have to get the messages and then parse the response to get the names.

```
function getName($id) 
{ 
$facebookUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$id; 
$str = file_get_contents($facebookUrl); 
$result = json_decode($str); 
return $result->name; 
}
```

Please help me how can i get the name when getting messages using FQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fql multiquery: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/

```
$queries = array(
    'messages' => 'SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, attachment, viewer_id FROM message WHERE thread_id = <thread_id>',
    'users' => 'SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT author_id FROM #messages)',
);

$param = array(
    'method'   => 'fql.multiquery',
    'queries'  => json_encode($queries),
    'callback' => ''
);

try {
    $fqlresult = $facebook->api($param);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo "EXCEPTION {$e->getMessage()}\n";
}
```

Comment: I've added some example code for you; you may have to make some changes depending on your exact requirements.